# R cannot be resolved to a variable | Could not find [YourAndroiProjectName].apk

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Every new Android project create via Eclipse and ADT plugin in Eclipse show an error

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

in every R call.
[image]

If I delete all references to the R class, when I try to build and run the app, it shows in the console :

```
Could not find [YourAndroiProjectName].apk
```

[image]

Comment: For me the same thing was in the project build path I had to check that new library in order and export tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open: 
Android SDK Build-tools

[image]

Make sure that you installed the Android SDK Build-tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the R file if your code has no errors eclipse should rebuild it automatically.

Comment: Actually, I have made the answer myself.

And in that situation, there was no "R" file.

Folder gen was empty.